# android / database / SqLite / ORM

Tags: android, sqlite

i am very beginner in android development and i was trying to create a simple 
app withe database (SqlLite) with main operation such as insert , update ,etc

i tried to use library like (Realm or SugarORM) but it gives me err when
i try to store the object i have create in the Database 
the emulator gives me this message:

> unfortunately my_app_name has stopped

it gives me that err no matter what emulator i used

this is the part of code when it is give me the wrong

```
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(getApplicationcontext);
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(car);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Note i have No syn text err 
Note i also get this err in logcat

```
E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
```

and finally i am sorry for my bad English

Comment: where are your logcat ?

Comment: post the LogCat, ignore OpenGL issues for now, because they are not relevant to DB transactions.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is do not use third party libraries as a beginner.
Try to look at android official training documents: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html
And android api documents:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db